# Binding an ObservableList<CheckBox> to an HBox's children in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I was expecting to be able to do something such as:

```
ObservableList<CheckBox> checkboxes = ...;
HBox hbox = new HBox();
hbox.childrenProperty.bind(checkboxes);
```

but there seems to be no `childrenProperty`. Is it possible to somehow (easily and idiomatically) bind the elements of an HBox (or any other layout, for that matter) to an ObservableList?

The problem I'm trying to "solve" is to be able to be able to not have to have this kind of logic on the view -- I wanted to make this mapping such that then I could just map the view controls to my ViewModel's properties / bindings and keep all my logic at that level.

Thanks

Comment: How about binding using a listener:    `checkboxes.addListener( (ListChangeListener.Change<? extends CheckBox> c) ->{
     /* respond to list change */
    });` ?

Comment: And implement all the update logic myself? I was expecting something a bit more high level.

Answer (score 4):

After some back and forth I actually found a way to do it:

```
ObservableList<CheckBox> checkboxes = ...;
Bindings.bindContent(hbox.getChildren(), checkboxes);
```